# Unable to add Mecurial Repo to TeamCity v9.1.1

Tags: mercurial, teamcity, tortoisehg

I am attempting to add an existing Mercurial bitbucket repo to a clean installation of TeamCity.
I have tried multiple repos including one created from scratch just a test.
I have attempted to do this on two separate installations of TeamCity on two different machines from two different physical locations.

I have tried specifying the Hg Command within TeamCity as 'Hg' as well as the actual path to both a plain Mercurial install and a TortoiseHg install.

Each time TeamCity attempts to check out the repo it fails, with this error:

```
Failed for the root '"mercurial: https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx" 
{instance     id=12, parent internal id=2, parent id=xxxxx, description:
"mercurial: https://bitbucket.org/xxxxx"}: 'hg init' command failed.
stderr: abort: repository . already exists!
```

I have been able check out Git repos with no issue.
Is it me, or should TeamCity not even be calling 'hg init'?
I would very much appreciate some assistance on this problem.

Comment: That you're seeing a message that the repo already exists at least indicates that the hg commands are running correctly. Do you have Versioned Settings enabled on the project that you're trying to add this VCS root to? And can you show us the settings you're using for the VCS root?

Comment: Ok, so in my frustration at trying to solve the issue I wiped my install of TeamCity and installed an older version (9.0.4) from April this year and it worked first time.  Weird huh?  So maybe this is an issue with TC itself.  TC is now prompting me to upgrade, I will do so and see if this breaks the build configuration.